# Handshake inactivity timeout error AWS node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

i'm quite new with node.js. usually i'm connect the AWS through java but this time i needed to change from java based to node.js with lambda service. i have simple connection from node.js to AWS RDS Database,

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
    var config = require('./config.json');
    var pool = mysql.createPool({
        host: config.dbhost,
        user: config.dbuser,
        password: config.dbpassword,
        database: config.dbname,
    });
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        // Use the connection
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            connection.query('Select 1+1 as numberss', function (error, results, fields) {
            // And done with the connection.
            connection.release();
            // Handle error after the release.
            if (error) throw error;
            else console.log(results);
            process.exit();
            // Don't use the connection here, it has been returned to the pool
            });
        }
    });
```

i've tried so many ways that i'm search in internet like adding timeout, check host information and etc.

but it's seem to return

```
{ Error: Handshake inactivity timeout
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (/Users/HAUZDevTeam/HAUZ-HQ-Lambda/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:160:17)
    at Handshake.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Handshake._onTimeout (/Users/HAUZDevTeam/HAUZ-HQ-Lambda/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:124:8)
    at Timer._onTimeout (/Users/HAUZDevTeam/HAUZ-HQ-Lambda/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Timer.js:32:23)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/HAUZDevTeam/HAUZ-HQ-Lambda/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/HAUZDevTeam/HAUZ-HQ-Lambda/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/Users/HAUZDevTeam/HAUZ-HQ-Lambda/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/Users/HAUZDevTeam/HAUZ-HQ-Lambda/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/HAUZDevTeam/HAUZ-HQ-Lambda/local.js:9:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
  code: 'PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT',
  fatal: true,
  timeout: 10000 }
```

is there any way to overcome this error or is there any wrong thing that i did on my code?

Comment: did you check your security groups inbound connection?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra, the inbound source was
type: MSSQL protocol:TCP  port:1433 source: 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Well, that explains it. You enabled MSSQL instead of MYSQL

Comment: sorry, @slebetman is it means that need to create one more security group using mysql type?

Comment: can i know the exact reason why or when to using MSSQL / MYSQL

Comment: You use Microsoft SQL when you are using Microsoft SQL server. When you are using Oracle's MySQL server (which is a different incompatible software) you need to use MySQL. It's like you install Windows version of apps on Windows and Mac version of apps on Mac

Comment: The main difference in this case is that Microsoft uses port 1433 for Microsoft SQL (MS usually means Microsoft) and Oracle uses port 3306 for MySQL. So the reason you cannot connect is you have not opened port 3306 in your security groups

Comment: Note that if this server setting works for your Java program then you may be having the opposite problem - you are trying to use a mysql library to access a Microsoft SQL server. In which case you need to rewrite your node.js app to use mssql